# Error Code: 1305 MySQL, Function does not Exist

Tags: mysql, function

I have a problem. I created a function in MySQL which returns a String (varchar data type).

Here's the syntax:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `inv_sbmanis`$$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `SafetyStockChecker`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `SafetyStockChecker`
(jumlah INT, safetystock INT)   
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
DECLARE statbarang VARCHAR(10);
IF jumlah > safetystock THEN SET statbarang = "Stabil";
ELSEIF jumlah = safetystock THEN SET statbarang = "Perhatian";
ELSE SET statbarang = "Kritis";
END IF;
RETURN (statbarang);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call the function like `call SafetyStockChecker(16,16)`, I get this error:

> Query : call SafetyStockChecker(16,16)
>       Error Code : 1305
>       PROCEDURE inv_sbmanis.SafetyStockChecker does not exist
>       Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
>       Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
>       Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

What's wrong with the function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is not the correct way to call a function. Here's an example to call a function:

```
SELECT SafetyStockChecker(16,16) FROM TableName
```

The way you are doing now is for calling a `STORED PROCEDURE`. That is why the error says:

> PROCEDURE inv_sbmanis.SafetyStockChecker does not exist

because it is searching for a Stored procedure and not a function.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
SELECT SafetyStockChecker(16,16)
```